# Windows 8: your pc ran into a prob., unexepcted kernel mode trap

Tags: windows-8, kernel-panic

I'm writing here because I read and tried many solutions to fix this problem on my windows 8 but none of them has worked up to now. I still launched a file system check with `sfc /scannow` but it was useless.

Then I've tried to go Computer->properties-> adavanced properties->startup and recovery-> and I've disabled "Automatic reboot" and selected "memory dump Comleted" in wiriting information debug.

Nothing again.

How can I fix this annoying problem? I don't know windows very much, if you can tell me what and where I have to check (logs for example) it would be very useful for me. 
My pc (Sony Vaio sve1513q1esi) was native with windows 8 so there shouldn't be problems with hardware drivers.

Usually I work on Ubuntu but unfortunately sometimes I must use windows too.

Comment: zip and upload the following file (**C:\Windows\memory.dmp**) to Skydrive,dropbox and add a link. I'll look at it with a debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry but there's no file like that... :( I've looked for it in the whole hard disk but I can't find it

Comment: is the pagefile enabled and large enough to catch a kernel dump?